# Virustotal flag 32 bit version of my program as malware

Tags: c#, visual-studio, x86, malware, antivirus

I've run into a very odd thing. I wrote a pretty simple program in C#, and tried  to build a 32bit and a 64bit version of it. The 64bit version works fine, but whenever i try to build the 32bit version, my antivirus software removes it. I've uploaded both files to virustotal here:

32 bit: https://virustotal.com/da/file/fdb3d2870ce876b49eb5d9371fc0b133b7657ddd994603777a42a47f3eb09d8b/analysis/1461779525/

64 bit:
https://virustotal.com/da/file/83334954cb0baef30153ca8bdfa900b64fef33f1983899c9e54e9156b72df00c/analysis/1461779699/

Why? its completely the same code, and  the only difference is that i switched between x64 and x86 before they were build.

Comment: here is the project(VS2015) https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/83131608/ResistorLookup.7z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set your project to AnyCPU after removing the P/Invokes from your code. That way you don't need a x86 and a x64 build.

I don't see anything in your project which looks off, except the use of the following lines:

```
    [DllImport("psapi.dll")]
    static extern int EmptyWorkingSet(IntPtr hwProc);

    static void MinimizeFootprint()
    {
        EmptyWorkingSet(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle);
    }

    ... 

    GC.Collect();
    MinimizeFootprint();
```

Given your small application there really should be no need to call the Garbage Collector manually and to tweak the workingset. [There are known issues with using it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1812035/736079).

Instead just clean up your brushes when you're done with them:

```
private void DrawResistor(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    SolidBrush brs;

    //Første farve
    g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 130, 35, 130, 109);
    g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 140, 35, 140, 109);
    using (brs = new SolidBrush(this.Controls.Find(Farver[0], false)[0].BackColor))
    {
        g.FillRectangle(brs, 131, 35, 9, 75);
    }

    //Anden farve
    g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 160, 44, 160, 100);
    g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 170, 44, 170, 100);
    using (brs = new SolidBrush(this.Controls.Find(Farver[1], false)[0].BackColor))
    {
        g.FillRectangle(brs, 161, 44, 9, 56);
    }

    //Tredje farve  
    if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex != 0)
    {
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 190, 44, 190, 100);
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 200, 44, 200, 100);
        using (brs = new SolidBrush(this.Controls.Find(Farver[2], false)[0].BackColor))
        {
            g.FillRectangle(brs, 191, 44, 9, 56);
        }
    }

    //Fjerde farve
    g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 220, 44, 220, 100);
    g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 230, 44, 230, 100);
    using (brs = new SolidBrush(this.Controls.Find(Farver[3], false)[0].BackColor))
    {
        g.FillRectangle(brs, 221, 44, 9, 56);
    }

    //Femte farve
    g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 265, 35, 265, 109);
    g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 280, 35, 280, 109);
    using (brs = new SolidBrush(this.Controls.Find(Farver[4], false)[0].BackColor))
    {
        g.FillRectangle(brs, 266, 35, 14, 75);
    }

    //Sjette farve
    if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 2)
    {
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 293, 35, 293, 109);
        g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 303, 35, 303, 109);
        using (brs = new SolidBrush(this.Controls.Find(Farver[5], false)[0].BackColor))
        {
            g.FillRectangle(brs, 294, 35, 9, 75);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! just before i posted my code i found that i set picturebox1.image inside the OnPaint event, so thats why it was using almost 80MB at the time. I fixed that, and forgot to remove the collect call, and the other API tweak. I've removed that part and when i recompile with x86 as target, it still flags the .exe file. Very strange! https://virustotal.com/da/file/7c306c6c1bf2803add0cc3b7541c2566f0995054c81a9f725459f22249cb9a47/analysis/1462114085/

Comment: This is the new project files https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/83131608/ResistorLookup2.7z

Comment: The binary looks fine, my own Anti-Virus doesn't flag it either. Nothing more you can do than flag the false positive with you Anti-virus supplier. PS: You should really use the using statements to dispose of your brushes.

Comment: What happens when you compile it as AnyCPU? You have no need to compile as x86 and x64 specifically as far as I can tell...

Comment: thanks for your replies and sorry for my late answers. Yes the AnyCPU option works fine actually. I dont quite know how that works but i will read up on that :) About the brush, couldn't i just put brs.Dispose() at the end of the function, instead of that using() statement?

Comment: I just think its odd that it flags the 32 bit version, i really dont see why.. EDIT: aha, i only get weekly email updates about new replies..

Comment: You should dispose each instance of a brush you create. By disposing at the end you only dispose the **last** created instance.